# Has device [storage] browsing through Bluetooth been disabled on Android?

Tags: bluetooth, file-management

My mobile phone is a [Motorola Moto G](http://i-cdn.phonearena.com/images/phones/43973-xlarge/Motorola-Moto-X-3a.jpg) with Android 5.1 and I've just discovered I could no longer browse my phone storage through Bluetooth. I only use that feature infrequently yet I find it extremely practical. I usually connect to my phone from [Linux Mint](http://linuxmint.com) — which I love precisely for the hassle-free usage when it comes to such manipulations. The software I use is [BlueMan](https://github.com/blueman-project/blueman) Bluetooth Manager.

Today I uploaded a spreadsheet file to my phone, which I wanted to use as a temporary storage. As a side note, it refused the ODS extension (WTF?)... well, saved it as .xlsx (sighs) and my phone accepted it. As there's no [stock] application that allows me to browse my phone storage locally — hadn't needed any so far — I thought about retrieving the file on the other computer with Blueman «*Browse device...*» feature. I got an error such as this one:

> Oops, something went wrong. Service not available on the remote device.

I then removed my phone from Blueman's list, refreshed the list and added my phone to Blueman again.

Surprise: «*Browse device...*» is now grayed. I tried on another computer and it's the same issue.

The only way I could retrieve the file on a computer was to install Asus ZenUI [File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.asus.filemanager) on my phone, browse locally to find the file in question and send (share through bluetooth) it to the computer...

I wouldn't call this a hassle-free experience, especially given that remote browsing *was* possible some time ago.

So did Google actually remove Bluetooth Remote Browsing?

Comment: Have you considered flashing custom kernels? Lollipop kernels are pretty locked down when stock.

Comment: @aaron-gillion : I suppose that implies rooting my phone?

Comment: Yeah pretty much... There is a downgrade to Kitkat guide available for the Moto G, that will definitely fix the problem immediately. Just for info, Google is not responsible at all for Bluetooth Remote Browsing. That's all implemented by BlueMan. Contact the dev there, they should've rolled out an update for Lollipop by now...

Comment: I'd less reluctantly root my phone if it was a testing device so that's no option to me yet. You know, given that Google is no stranger to removing features (such as silent or vibrate modes) I had to ask. But thanks for the info, I'll check a fairly recent Blueman stack and see if it helps.

Comment: Did you upgrade the software on your device?  I don't see the connection to Google here.

Comment: Yes, I always apply updates and upgrades to my Android phone when there are. The last upgrade was a long time before I posted this message. There's been a lot of updates since then though. About my computer, it's been a long time there's been no updates applied. And isn't Google the company behind [the product named] Android? You know, like Microsoft is behind [the product named] Windows, right?